# Razor embed html tags inside a text based brackets

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

On the Server I'm setting ViewBag.Something = "Hello"

This is some simple HTML code:

```
<tr>
   <td class="foo">  
     @("please highlight" + Html.Raw("<span style='color: yellow;'>) +     
        ViewBag.Something + Html.Raw("</span>") + ", " + ViewBag.More)
   </td>
</tr>
```

My goal is to see Hello displayed in **YELLOW** color and I need to use the @( with various fields here)

Using the above code, I get this wrong result

```
please highlight < span style='color: yellow;'>Hello< /span>, More
```

where the **span tag** is displayed as text on the html page

**QUESTION:**
What do I need to do in razor so that the SPAN tag becomes a real Span when using a @(xxx) syntax?

Comment: Are you sure that's the *exact* code you're using?  Because there's nothing there which would cause the HTML to display raw, but there's *also* no `@` to invoke the server-side processing so the output should actually say "ViewBag.Something" instead of "Hello".

Comment: @David ...I fixed the @ but the issue is that I'm getting the < span > displayed as text.

Comment: Then there's either something wrong with your server/framework/etc. or there's more code to this.  Honestly, there's nothing wrong with that first example.  That's normal valid HTML with a single razor-interpreted value.

Comment: @David my mistake, I asked the wrong question. I guess I was trying and trying various scenarios and lost the main focus. Please see now

Answer (score 2):

The following should suffice (although your first example should also suffice, I'm guessing that there's actually more to it, this way the parenthesis make the code statement more explicit):

```
<tr>
 <td class="foo">  
   please highlight <span style="color: yellow;">@(ViewBag.Something)</span>
 </td>
</tr>
```

For future reference you may find [Phil Haack's Razor syntax cheat sheet](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) useful.

Comment: My mistake, my real problem is when I need to bracket the entire line that contains various variables ....in that case (I re-wrote my question), the < span > gets displayed.

Comment: You do not need to bracket the entire line, merely the part that needs to be evaluated as C# code, in this instance, just the call to `ViewBag.Something`. The parser is smart enough to figure out that the rest is supposed to be written to the output stream as is. You do not need to and should not have the `span` tags inside the `@` block.